# How do I refer to an inactive sheet when doing a paste values?

Tags: vba, excel, paste, autofill

I am new to VBA in Excel. I am trying to write a code that pastes the value of a cell into another cell and then autofills to a specific range in the same column. How can I do this in the background without the sheet being active? This is the code that the Macro Recorder wrote:

```
Sheets("Results").Select
Range("D8").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("E8").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E8"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E2:E8").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E44"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E2:E44").Select
Columns("E:E").EntireColumn.AutoFit
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify an inactive workbook or worksheet by using something like this: `Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1")`.

For example:

```
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D8").Copy
Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E8").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked really well for the copy portion, do you know how to do the autofill?

Comment: You can use `Range("E2:E44").PasteSpecial` to paste to the entire range rather than just Cell E8 (I'm not sure if you're copying a formula or a value). The code below will use autofill, let me know if this works:

`Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E8").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("E2:E44")`

Answer (score 0):

Work with range objects, explicitly defined to their parent worksheets (and possibly Workbooks, if needed):

```
Dim copyRange as Range
Dim destRange as Range

Set copyRange = Sheets("Results").Range("D8")  'Or Workbooks("Book1").Sheets("SheetName").Range("D8")
Set destRange = Sheets("Other Sheet").Range("E8")  'Or Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Another Sheet").Range("E8")
copyRange.copy
destRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
destRange.AutoFill destRange.Offset(-7, 0).Resize(8, 1), xlFillDefault
destRange.AutoFill destRange.Resize(36, 1), xlFillDefault

destRange.EntireColumn.Autofit
```

It was not clear to me when/if you changed worksheets during the macro recorder session, and it wasn't clear to me the various selections/autofills you were doing.  Let me know if you need help figuring those parts out, I took a guess at it above.

Here is another method you could probably use:

```
Dim copyRange as Range
Dim destRange as Range
Dim dt as Date
Set copyRange = Sheets("Results").Range("D8")
Set destRange = Sheets("Other Sheet").Range("E2")  

dt = DateAdd("d", -6, DateValue(copyRange.Value))  'get the value 6 days before
copyRange.Copy destRange 'copy the formatting/etc
destRange.Value = dt     'insert the value
destRange.AutoFill destRange.Resize(44, 1), xlFillDefault
destRange.EntireColumn.Autofit
```

Comment: Thanks the copy part worked really well. I still cant get the autofill to work with this code. I get a "compile error: Expected: End of Statement". To try to explain better I am only working on the "results" sheet and I am trying to copy D8 to E8 then autofill E8 up to E2 and down to E44. Let me know if you need more info and thanks again!

Comment: OK that makes sense now but why not just copy to E2 and autofill down to E44?

Comment: There was a typo and a missing comma in that line, I've fixed it to autofill from E8:E44. Can you explan why you need to autofill twice, instead of just pasting to E2 and fill down to E44?

Comment: Cell E8 is a date pulled from another source. I need to autofill 6 days before that date and 36 after it.

Comment: Hmmmm try revision above (assuming you want to increment/decrement the date value from `E8`.